# Ruby's 'next' method experiment

Tags: ruby

Starting from:

```
"1a"
```

[edit update]
I would like to iterate through successive strings 1a 1b 1c... to say 2a or any number with the alphabetic letter using String#next method only. It's not part of Enumerable so I want to just use next for each successive String.

```
"1a".next # => 1b
```

We get the first one but how could we get the next one from there. Perhaps save it as a variable? I'm not sure how to do it. How may we do this without Range or Enumerate?

```
# => 1c
...
# => 2a
```

Keep in mind a method would be nice even if you want to yield a block.

Comment: What is your question, btw?

Answer (score 3):

The `Range` class uses `#next` for iteration:

```
('1a'..'2a').each { |x| puts x }
```

Comment: I updated the question. So does String and I want to use that only. But thanks. Works fine.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-upto) would work:

> The `String#succ` method is used to generate each value.

```
'1a'.upto('2a') { |str| puts str }
#=> 1a
#   1b
#   1c
#   ...
#   1x
#   1y
#   1z
#   2a
```

Or `'1a'.upto('2a', true) { ... }` to omit the last value, i.e. `'2a'`

Comment: I updated the question but yes this works fine. Thanks!